Is a comma between a time phrase and an independent clause (in that order) a must?

We can see that in 2007 there were three bus stops on either side of Hospital Road.
 However, by 2010 this original car park had become a designated area for staff parking only.

These are two sentences written by a native teacher, and I wonder why there isn't a comma on the right of each year.
As far as I know, these time phrases are similar in function to an adverb, so why do we need a comma after an adverb and before an independent clause while it's not the case for a time phrase?
Actually, in another sentence, he also wrote:

In 2007, staff and visitors used the same car park...

Why did he add a comma in this case then? Thank you!

You want "We can see that in 2007, there were three bus stops..."? Or to set off "in 2007" with commas on either side? The first is very odd; the second is possible but IMO unnecessary. And it's a matter of opinion.

Your teacher is probably flying by the seat of his or her pants and intuitively placing a comma where there would be a slight pause in speech, corresponding to a phrase contour or parsing rhythm.  When a phrase like "In 2007" introduces a sentence there is often a little pause after it. It has pride-of-place, as it were. It has a special importance. But if it occurs "mid-stream" it could be less important, in which case no pause and no commas; or it could be very important and set off with commas on either side, representing pauses that isolate the phrase for emphasis.

Thank you both for the explanation! @TimR "flying by the seat of their pants" is meant to criticize them, isn't it? So could you tell me how else it should be written?

No, not criticism. Just without instruments. (See the book Night Flight by Antoine de Saint-Exupéry.)  The "instruments" in this case would be some set of punctuation rules that say where commas should be placed; but there are no such instruments, only preferred conventions and consensus opinion of various style sheets, and there are things on which reasonable people can disagree.

I think this comma is generally considered optional.
